# Выборка из базы нужного определенного количества строк и общей суммы количества

Tags: php, mysql

В базе есть, допустим, 20 строк. Мне нужно выбрать из них 4 для показа и общее количество. К примеру, двумя запросами это выглядело бы так:

```
$db->Query("SELECT COUNT(*) count FROM `table` WHERE условие");
$row=$db->RowArray();
echo $row["count"];

$db->Query("SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE условие LIMIT 0,4");
while($row=$db->RowArray()){
    echo $row["name"];
}
```

Как можно их объединить без вложенного запроса?

Comment: На сколько я знаю во всех фреймворках пагинаторы предполагают выполнение двух запросов. Один считает общее кол-во записей, а другой читает данные для конкретной страницы. Так что ваш вариант почти классический.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Вариант 1:

```
SELECT *, q.count_all
FROM table_name
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all
    FROM table_name
    WHERE /* условие */
) q
WHERE /* условие */
```

Вариант 2:

```
SELECT COUNT(*)
FROM table_name
WHERE /* условие */
INTO @count_all;

SELECT *, @count_all AS count_all
FROM table_name
WHERE /* условие */;
```

Вариант 3:

```
SELECT
    *,
    (
        SELECT COUNT(*)
        FROM table_name
        WHERE /* условие */
    ) AS count_all
FROM table_name
WHERE /* условие */
```

Первый и второй лучше. Запрос на кол-во считается один раз. В третьем он будет вычисляться для каждой строки в таблице.

Comment: Плюс, но ни один из вариантов мне не подходит к сожалению. Поэтому оставлю как есть, наверное

Comment: Еще используют [`SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS`][1]

  [1]: http://habrahabr.ru/post/81034/

Comment: Ответ принял, но оставил все как было. Двумя запросами.

Answer (score 0):

Никак. Если `условие` и в первом и во втором запросе одинаковое, то Вы можете добавить дополнительный столбец во второй запрос, в котором 4 раза вывести значение счетчика.

```
$db->Query("SELECT COUNT(*) count, `field1`, `field2`, `field3` FROM `table` WHERE условие LIMIT 0,4");
$row=$db->RowArray();
echo $row["count"];
while($row=$db->RowArray()){
    echo $row["name"];
}
```

Хотя в Вашем случае 2 запроса выглядят красивее и, думаю, отработаю быстрее.

Comment: Разве в таком случае count не будет равно 4?

Comment: Прошу прощения, действительно выведет не то, что нужно. Счетчик выведет правильно, но только 1 строку :)

Comment: @Vitalii Maslianok, так делать нельзя.

Если в `SELECT` есть агрегатная функция и нет группировки, запрос вернет одну строку. `COUNT(*)` выведет общее кол-во записей, а остальные поля будут содержать первые значения из списка.

Comment: @KiTE да, это я понял. Но уж больно хотелось, чтобы заработало :)

Comment: @KiTE с вложением да - работает! Но это сильно сказывается на скорость при 20К-30К записей в таблице...

Comment: @Ёхарный Бабай, на скорости может отразиться только 3-й вариант. Потому что расчет общего кол-ва производится для каждой строки. В 1-м и 2-м кол-во считается только 1 раз.

Попробуй 2-й, он самый вменяемый для использования с условиями.

Comment: Перенес комментарий в отдельный ответ.